# White space on right/bottom border after creation of yxz-tiles using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I use a 16384 x 16384 pixel large .tiff file to create a game map with QGIS.

The coordinate reference system in QGIS is EPSG:3857 and I visualize the map with leaflet (https://leafletjs.com/).

QGIS has the great feature to create the xyz-tiles. My problem are the image tiles on the right and bottom border of the map because they include white space, which doesn't look good on the final map (in leaflet).

The parameter extent (on creating xyz-tiles) has the value "calculate on layer" and this layer is is square with a size of 2^14 pixel. The parameters tile width and height are 256 pixel (2^8). So I'm wondering about this white space on the image tiles.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: The tiling schema of EPSG:3857 is fixed and your image can only fill completely all the tiles if the image extents fits exactly with the tiling grid. You could define a custom grid but Leaflet may have difficult to show it. Another option is to crop your image to EPSG:3857 tiles. Maybe the site https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/#3/11.74/62.72 can help with finding how to crop.

Comment: JPEG or PNG tiles?

Comment: JPEG, I have just tried an export with PNG tiles. In this case the white space is transparent and it looks better.

Comment: The problem with PNG is, all tiles have a total size of 340 MB vs. 80 MB with JPEGs. So I prefer  an export with JPEGs.

Comment: JPEG does not support transparency. Some other programs have an option to save partially filled tiles as PNG and full tiles as JPEG.